# Simplifying an Expression by Using Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have this expression: X'YZ'+X'YZ+XY'Z'+XYZ'+XYZ (' means not)
I know the answer is Y+XZ' but I am stuck in the last part. Can anyone give me a hand?

This is what I got so far:

```
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XY'Z' + XYZ' + XYZ
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XZ'(Y' + Y) + XYZ
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XZ' + XYZ
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XYZ + XZ'
Y(X'Z' + X'Z + XZ) + XZ'   
Y(1) + XZ'   # I am not sure if is there is a rule that makes (X'Z+X'Z+XZ)= 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of is this (i.e. using `XYZ'` twice):

```
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XY'Z' + XYZ' + XYZ
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XY'Z' + XYZ' + XYZ + XYZ'
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XZ'(Y' + Y) + XYZ + XYZ'
X'YZ' + X'YZ + XYZ + XYZ'+ XZ'
Y(X'Z' + X'Z + XZ + XZ') + XZ'
Y(1) + XZ'   
Y + XZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with `X'YZ'+X'YZ+XY'Z'+XYZ'+XYZ`

(¬X ∧ Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨
 (¬X ∧ Y ∧ Z) ∨
 (X ∧ ¬Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨
 (X ∧ Y ∧ ¬Z) ∨
 (X ∧ Y ∧ Z) ↔ ⊤

Construct a Karnaugh map http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

```
XY 00 01 11 10
Z 0 0  1  1  1
  1 0  1  1  0
```

Reduce to Y ∨ (X ∧ ¬Z) in two steps.